# evaluating numpy polynomials at other polynomials

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math

numpy.lib.polynomial.polyval lets you evaluate a polynomial using another polynomial:

```
numpy.polyval(poly1d([1, 2, 3]), 2)
Out[832]: 11

numpy.polyval(poly1d([1, 1]), poly1d([1, 1, 1]))
Out[820]: poly1d([ 1.,  1.,  2.])
```

for instance.  How do you do the same using numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval?

```
numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(2, [3, 2, 1])
Out[833]: 11.0

numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(Polynomial([1, 1, 1]), Polynomial([1, 1]))
Out[834]: Polynomial([ 1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])
```

Comment: Why? Not to be too blunt, but you have a solution why the question? These two functions have different behaviour for a reason.

Comment: @MrAlias: There are 2 different APIs with different polynomial objects.  I am trying to use the newer one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the Polynomial class.

```
In [1]: from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

In [2]: p1 = P([1,1])

In [3]: p2 = P([1,1,1])

In [4]: p2(p1)
Out[4]: Polynomial([ 3.,  3.,  1.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])

In [5]: p1(p2)
Out[5]: Polynomial([ 2.,  1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])
```

If you insist on polyval, you need both the coefficients, and a polynomial to use as x.

```
In [12]: import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

In [13]: poly.polyval(p1, [1,1,1])
Out[13]: Polynomial([ 3.,  3.,  1.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])

In [14]: poly.polyval(p2, [1,1])
Out[14]: Polynomial([ 2.,  1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])
```

Comment: I swear I tried that and it wasn't working.  Maybe I had the coefficient order screwed up.